# Profile picture upload blocked at 600px - Ultimate Members plugin Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, upload

I have a problem with the Ultimate Member plugins, as soon as I want to upload a profile photo when registering, the image must be at least 600px, but I can't change this value.

https://herault-entreprises.fr/register/

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You probably just need to change the plugin settings then ...? https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1554-profile-cover-size

Comment: No these parameters are simply for display on the profile or directory page, my problem comes when uploading the image during registration

Comment: Are you sure those two things are not related? If you demand that a thumbnail of 600px size should be created via plugin settings, then it would make sense that it automatically rejects any attempts to upload smaller images.

Comment: I agree except we have filled in 40px, 80px, 190px for the profile photo size, I'm not talking about the cover photo. And even with this setting it rejects a photo smaller than 600px

Comment: I found it is enough simply to modify it is 4 lines in the class-fields.php files. [../plugins/ultimate-member/includes/cores/class-fields.php] 

if ( $array['min_width'] == '' && $array['crop'] == 1 ) {         $array['min_width'] = 200;
}
if ( $array['min_height'] == '' && $array['crop'] == 1 ) {      $array['min_height'] = 200;     
}
if ( $array['min_width'] == '' && $array['crop'] == 3 ) {      $array['min_width'] = 200;
}
if ( $array['min_height'] == '' && $array['crop'] == 3 ) {      $array['min_height'] = 200;
}

Comment: But plugin files should rather not be modified directly, otherwise you'll loose your modifications with the next plugin update ... Not sure which 4 lines you are referring to, but you should check if there isn't any hook available in that place to modify the relevant values from the outside.

Comment: Can't find those lines in https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/blob/master/includes/core/class-files.php (but perhaps you are using an older plugin version.)